# Present continuous and present simple

Tags: present-tense, continuous-aspect

can I use present continuous and present simple in one sentence, like in my writings below?

1."There is no bird singing without a reason so don't tell me you cry for no cause."

2."The moments I don't think about you, I just think about why I'm not thinking about you"

Comment: There is no rule in English about using those two tenses in a sentence except that they have to make sense.Bu the way, in 1) there is no present continuous at all.

Comment: In 1., a comma is required after reason; else it looks fused.  In 2., check if it is "The moments..." or "The moment....

Comment: Perhaps more fundamental than any of that is that you begin a sentence with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use all tenses in one sentence if you so desire.

   https://www.quora.com/How-many-tenses-can-you-get-in-one-sentence

   I believe that all languages are able to do that.
2. in your first sentence   *no bird singing* singing is a Gerund not an active verb.

Comment: Nah, "no bird singing" in this sentence is gerund.

Comment: I stand corrected.